# How to add a "add feed to calendar" button to a website?

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm looking to add a button to my website which lets the user add my calendar to his calendar. 
I should explain - I know how to make a button that adds to your calendar a specific event, but I want to add an entire calendar to the user's Google Account.

I have an XML URL of my calendar, like this: `https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/cjohljus7r*******omlg03a8h0%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic`.

I know this is possible, because when you embed a calendar in a website there's a little button which does what I want:

[image: screenshot of calendar embed]

(Look at the bottom-right corner)

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Google Calendar V2 is deprecated. You have to use calendar V3. check this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Comment: Hey, I don't mind which API I use, as long as it works. Please give me a relevant solution :)

Comment: You could do a calendarList.insert() method call from the above mentioned API but you will need your users to authenticate. Another option if you want a browser-only solution, you can use https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=<YOUR_CALENDAR_EMAIL> which will add the calendar through the UI.